# Why isn't my form saving but working with the API only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have my form to save to my Stripe_account table.  I recently nested the resources and now the form won't save to my database tables.  I have it still working with the Stripe API and working there though.

What in my code is lacking?

User Model:

```
  has_one :stripe_account
```

Stripe_account Model:

```
  belongs_to :users
```

Stripe_account controller:

```
    def new
        @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

      end

    def create

        @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
          acct = Stripe::Account.create({
.....
.....
    @stripe_account.id = current_user.id
    @stripe_account.acct_id = acct.id

  respond_to do |format|

      # @user = User.find(params[:id])

      if @stripe_account.save
        # current_user = @user
        @user.stripe_account = acct.id


        format.html { redirect_to new_bank_account_path, notice: 'Stripe account was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stripe_account }


      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stripe_account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View:

```
  <%= form_for ([@user, @stripe_account]) do | f | %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :stripe_accounts
  end

#added for testing 
  get 'stripe_' => "stripe_account#create"
  get 'stripe_new' => "stripe_account#new"
```

Here's my routes maybe can help?: https://pastebin.com/RVWd2Qq9

Now even though I don't have the "bankaccount" controller or models set up correctly yet, shouldn't it be at least attempting to go there and saving the stripe_account? Just making sure that's not the issue. But it appears it's failing because a new form reloads.

The API is successfully going through as well and the accounts are appearing within stripe, just not my own database.

What in my programming is wrong?

Update to add cmd response:

```
Started POST "/users/2/stripe_accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-10 00:11:26 -0500
Processing by StripeAccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nz1234567890iJuFwsm/Z4ylhE6zoGdWN6QCfWtDZTH1sxZu/WCdWMKBGkc4zoZ2dOgk9c8UDwRzgqdxrT/sA==", "stripe_account"=>{"account_type"=>"individual", "business_name"=>"", "business_tax_id"=>"", "first_name"=>"Dill", "last_name"=>"Pickles", "ssn_last_4"=>"1234", "dob_month"=>"3", "dob_day"=>"4", "dob_year"=>"1917", "address_line1"=>"198 berry avenue", "address_city"=>"san fran", "address_state"=>"CA", "address_postal"=>"90213", "tos"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}, "full_account"=>"{:value=>\"true\"}", "button"=>"", "user_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/stripe_accounts_controller.rb:49
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/stripe_accounts_controller.rb:91
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/stripe_accounts_controller.rb:91
  Rendering stripe_accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered stripe_accounts/_account_form.html.erb (9.4ms)
  Rendered stripe_accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3202ms (Views: 190.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the log that is appeared upon form submit?

Comment: thanks for responding.  just added the log from the cmd after the form submit

Comment: You have a rollback. Try changing `if @stripe_account.save` to `if @stripe_account.save!` so it will display any validation errors if there are any.

Comment: now i get "(Validation failed: User must exist)" when i have "belongs_to :user" and when i have "belongs_to :users" i get (Validation failed: Users must exist)...is my model wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Validation failed: User must exist

You can either use `optional :true` to resolve the error

```
#stipe_account.rb
belongs_to :user, optional: true
            #^ should be singular
```

**OR**

Assign the `user_id` in the `create` action like so

```
@stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id #add this line
```

**Update:**

> undefined method `user_id=' for StripeAccount:0x001234f4c58692ae8 Did
>   you mean? user="

The error is because you don't have `user_id` column in `stripe_accounts` table. Generate a migration that will do the job for you

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_stripe_accounts user_id:integer
```

and do `rails db:migrate`

Comment: So do both? Because i already have "    @stripe_account.id = current_user.id
" at the top of the create action.. is that the right spot or should it be after the stripe create section?

Comment: @uno `@stripe_account.id = current_user.id` is actually wrong! remove it from the create action. You should have `@stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id` instead.

Comment: With "@stripe_account.id = current_user.id" i get this error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed ... with user_id instead i get: undefined method `user_id=' for #<StripeAccount:0x001234f4c58692ae8> Did you mean? user="

Comment: @uno You should have `user_id` in the `stripe_accounts` table. Create a migration that will do the job for you.

Comment: what about the stripe_account "id"? just let that rack up and just associate the user_id with the User table id?

Comment: @uno You **should not** assign any custom values to `id`. Its a primary key which is auto-generated in the background. BTW, check my updated answer.

Comment: ooo ok. i thought it would be fine.  thanks for informing me on that.

Comment: It works! thanks... but i have one small issue.  The acct_id isn't saving the the User table under stripe_account.... should i be permitting it under the User Controller?